# Why isn't there "is not" keyword in c#?

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, types, keyword

It just makes sense sometimes to check if an object is not type of X, so you need to do this instead:

```
 if(this.GetType() != typeof(X)) 
 {
      //Do my thing.

 }
```

Which is a bit cumbersome to my opinion, would not something like this be nicer:

```
 if(this is not X) 
 {
     //Do my thing
 }
```

Comment: Those would not be functionally equivalent if `X` was a subtype of `this.GetType()`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

How about the logical NOT operator `!`, fits the description of the word 'not' just fine:

```
if (!(this is X)) 
{
    //Do my thing
}
```

As others have pointed out though, `is` is also used to check if an object's class inherits from some class or implements some interface, which is rather different from `GetType()`.

Both [CodeInChaos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4339863/why-isnt-there-is-not-keyword-in-c/4339947#4339947) and [StriplingWarrior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4339863/why-isnt-there-is-not-keyword-in-c/4339962#4339962) have reasonable explanations for why there isn't a `not` keyword in C#.

Comment: We wouldn't need to make `not` a keyword. It probably would be enough making `is not` a keyword similar to `yield return`. Might be a bit confusing since most C# programmers aren't used to two word keywords(or should I call them keyphrases?). So one would have to use `isnot` which IMO looks ugly.

Comment: I'd like to see "!" allowed in a few special cases in C where it would have clear meaning, but not presently be legal.  One case would be outside the parentheses for an if, while, etc. (in such contexts, it should strictly invert the condition, regardless of operator overloads).  Another such case might be good here: allow "this !is x", so as to avoid extra parentheses.

Answer (score 10):

Adding a keyword to a language adds complexity. Adding a keyword to a language after the initial specification could cause breaking changes for people upgrading. So keywords generally only get added if there's a very strong case for them. In this case, as the other answers point out, it is very easy to use the bang operator:

```
if (!(pero is Human)) ...
```

... which a typical C# (/C/C++/Java) developer would read "if not (pero is human)". So there's not much justification for a special keyword.

Comment: For example we have no `yield` keyword in C# because that would have been a breaking change. `yield return x` on the other hand was illegal syntax before and thus no breaking change.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: Yes, but an `is not` keyword could technically fall in the same category as `yield return`. The difference is that it takes a lot of work to emulate `yield return`, whereas the bang operator and parentheses suffice to emulate `is not`.

Comment: I believe an `isnot` operator (no spaces) would be very easy and safe to implement. I would definitely vote for it to be part of the C# syntax. So many times while coding fast I have almost written it. It comes very natural. It would also have intellisense and it would save all the bracket and negation operator typing. In short it would have been handy.

Answer (score 4):

Use good ol' bang symbol:

```
if (!(pero is Human)) 
{

}
```

BTW, `is` is different, because it catches not only leaf derived class, but whole hierarchy of it, both interfaces and classes.

So, for

```
class Human: ICanSpeak, Mamal
{
...
}

Human h;

if (h is Human)  {   will be true  }
if (h is ICanSpeak)  {  will be true  }
if (h is Mamal) {  will also be true  }
```

Answer (score 4):

Note that `this.GetType()` != `typeof(X)` returns false if this is derived from (or implements in case of an interface type) but not identical to X, whereas `this is X` returns true.

And why would there be a separate keyword when you can just use `!(a is X)`? That's bloating the language with little gain. As Eric Lippert likes to stress every new language feature needs to offer enough advantages to compensate for coding, documenting, testing and of course the increased complexity of the language. And a `not is` operator just doesn't offer enough.

You could implement an extension method, but I think that's stupid:

```
public static bool IsNot<T>(this object obj)
{
  return !(obj is T);
}
```

Comment: Aside from the fact that extension methods on object are a questionable programming practice, that's actually not a bad little extension method there. I'm not saying I'd use it, but I think it is pretty reasonable.

Comment: @Eric: I really wished C# had also have a not operator "not" in addition to !. One might say this is useless but ! is really hard to see/spot in code where as "if not (vector.IsNormalized)" is much easier to parse visually than "if !(vector.IsNormalized)", but I guess C# did it this way to not alienate C++ people, right?

Comment: @Eric, may I ask why object extensions methods are viewed as bad practice?

Comment: @Joan: Correct. I agree that the use of "!" to mean "not" is unnecessarily terse; basically it is a "secret code" that you have to know about in order to understand the meaning of the text. But as you note, this is idiomatic in C-like languages. In VB there is an "IsNot" operator, incidentally.

Comment: @Max: Because it is quite rare that it is sensible to have a method that works on strings, integers, tigers, documents, lists of bananas, types... Odds are good that any extension method on "object" is actually only sensible on a small subset of all possible objects. It's not a hard-and-fast rule, but it is a bit of a code smell.

Comment: @Eric: Thanks Eric. I never used VB but their Not operator looks really good. I can also imagine C# people thinking "Not" is more verbal so less elite, than having terse operators. I have actually been told this. Personally I don't like way verbose languages but for some of these things like "not" "and" "or" I think they are better than !, &&, ||. I also like when they are all lower caps like other C# keywords. But a change like this would certainly never be considered, right? Because of all the complications it might introduce.

Comment: I don't think it's stupid. There are lots of features done and still being added just to improve the readability of the code.